# Design DS for Multi-pattern Object

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures

There are various varieties of Shirt. **Varieties are based on parameters like pattern, size, colour, etc.**

Assuming you have all types of shirts available. Now there are various queries like:

*`Show all types of shirt having colour “red”.`*

*`Show all types of shirt having size “small” and pattern “checks” etc. etc.`*

So, assuming we have 'K' diffrent varieties ,and N shirts , what Data-structure can we design to store the following data , to answer the above queries in most optimal manner ?

**One obvious solution i thought is to store , 'K' instances of data , grouped according to each variety .But that will be very space in-efficient .**

What better can we do , keeping in mind the **space/time bounds** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about store `K` pointers for each item, indicates the next item with the same K-th variety .

Then for each query, pick one variety and enumerate all the items with that variety satisfied, check if it meets other constraints and show it. Thus take an `O(NK)` for each query and `O(1)` for adding a new item, while the space is `O(NK)`.

your scenario looks just like a database, why don't you check on that.

Comment: thats pretty much what i thought . thanx .